# Socket Error While accessing the web page

Tags: c#

When i try to access the web from outside of the company with the public IP it gives the socket error, but the same web i access within the company network with computer name it works perfect. All my configurations are up to date day before yesterday the public ip access was also ok but suddenly it stops. Below is the error which comes.

```
[SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address, Boolean     includeIPv6) +3175944
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress) +8767334
SIGS.Home.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +416
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,     Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

Comment: The error quite clearly says the DNS can't resolve the host. Have you tried with nslookup to see if that's really the issue?

Comment: Can you `ping` or do a `tracert` your host outside your company network? This sounds like a network problem.

Comment: Friends thanks for your help. I passed an entry on Network Layer to capture the IP of remote users who access it from out of office network the method written was not resolving the NETBIOS name. So i pass a fix value to the method.